# Which one is correct, "both in ... and in ..." or "in both ... and ..."?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

1. Asia is the largest continent, both in land and in population.
2. Asia is the largest continent, in both land and population.

I am confused because I've seen both of "both in ..." and "in both ...".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Both options are equally correct.